# SQL: wrong number of arguments to function Sum()

Tags: sql, pandas

I have a dataset with lots of columns. I need to do a `Group By ID` and then `SUM` over all the other columns (So, `ID` must NOT be aggregated).

Here is a small sample of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as ps

dt= {

"ID" : [1,2,1,4,2],
"A" : [2,3,4,5,6],
"B":[10,20,30,40,50],
"C": [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
}

dt= pd.DataFrame(dt)

dt= pd.DataFrame(dt)

query = """ 
                    select ID,Sum(*)
                    from dt
                    group by ID
             """

polyps = ps.sqldf(query)
```

But, it complains with:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) wrong number of arguments to function Sum()
[SQL:  
                    select ID,Sum(*)
                    from dt
                    group by ID
             ]
```

So, a proper output is:

```
   ID  A    B    C
0   1  6   40  400
1   2  9   70  700
2   4  5  700  400
```

Comment: What resuts do you want?

Comment: i will update my question @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want each column summed separately, you need to list them:

```
select ID, sum(a), sum(b), sum(c)
from dt
group by ID;
```

If you want the sum of all of them in one column:

```
select ID, sum(a) + sum(b) + sum(c)
from dt
group by ID;
```

`*` is only allowed for `count(*)` where the purpose is to count rows.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Id,(ISNULL(dt.val1,0) + ISNULL(dt.val2,0) + ISNULL(dt.val3,0)) as 'Total'
 from dt

The error "wrong number of arguments to function Sum()" says, instead of "*" you need to mention the fields inside SUM.